# Parse protobuf file in iOS applicaiton

Tags: ios, protocol-buffers

I am getting data file in the format of **.proto**, I am confronting this type of parsing for the first time. Could you please suggest how we can parse **.proto** file in the iOS app. I am very new with a protobuf file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am able to handle protoBuf formate data. I have used **Swift Protobuf** swift library for it. This is really a great library, it has awesome documentation. I am adding a reference here. https://github.com/apple/swift-protobuf